# SharePoint Task List integrated to Group Calender showing tasks to all members

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-calendar, task-list, user-tracking

I have added a Task List as a calender overlay to a master calender. The task assigned to my name is shown across all the members name and it is weird. Test Q and Test A are assigned only to my name but it is shown in every row. If anyone could have experience in working on complex projects in calender and task list, please help.

[image]

Comment: Please change a calendar view and compare the result. Per my test it works well. You could also add a screenshot of your task list.

Comment: Hi Julie.. the master calender is configured as a Group calender which shows people. I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, I found that group calendar works based on Attendees column exists in Schedule content type.

However, there is no such column in task list, so it will show all events of the task list.

[image]

Comment: Okay. Got it. Is there any workaround to suggest? Please help if possible.